# EhCache appears twice in JavaMelody

Tags: spring, ehcache, java-melody

In my application I have included the following xml configuration for EhCache (version 2.4.3 of ehcache-core)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd" 
         updateCheck="false"
         monitoring="autodetect" 
         dynamicConfig="true">

    <defaultCache  
        eternal="false"
        timeToIdleSeconds="0" 
        timeToLiveSeconds="0">
    </defaultCache>

    <cache name="MyParamsCache" 
        eternal="true" 
        overflowToDisk="true"
        diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="20" 
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"
        statistics="true">
    </cache>

</ehcache>
```

Cache manager is declared as

```
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager">
    <property name="cacheManager" ref="ehcache" />
</bean>

<bean id="ehcache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:ehcache.xml" />
</bean>
```

Using a bean I add parameters to this cache (by autowiring the cacheManager in Spring). There is no error in the application, but when I check the caches in JavaMelody (Data cashes section), I see that `MyParamsCache` appears twice. One instance is filled with content, while the other one is empty.

Does anyone have any idea why `MyParamsCache` appears twice and how to remove the dummy instance?

### EDITED

I also have hibernate second level cache in persistence.xml. The cache bean is created again there, instead of using the already existing one. The code is

```
<persistence-unit name="myPU">
        .....
        <properties>
                <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect" />
                <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
                <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true" />
                <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" />
                <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory" />
        </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is solved is file ehcache.xml is moved inside META-INF folder. Bean declaration is updated as

```
<bean id="ehcache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/ehcache.xml" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

i could solve the problem by adding ehcache as depends-on to the entityManagerFactory

```
        <bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
        id="entityManagerFactory" 
        depends-on="ehCache">
```

and in persistence.xml i configured

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory" />
```

i would be interrested in suggestions how i could achieve this without having to use SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory though.

Answer (score 0):

I posted this as an issue at https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody/issues/932 and found with the help of https://github.com/evernat the solution. For me, the solution was

1. To set the property `shared` of the main spring chacheManager `true`

```xml
    <bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:ehcache.xml"/>
        <property name="shared" value="true"/>
    </bean>
```

2. To use `SingletonEhCacheProvider` as the `hibernate.cache.provider_class`

```xml
    <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>   
    <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.SingletonEhCacheProvider</prop>
```